# Creating a exploded view - Export from Autodesk Inventor + multibody obj import

Tags: rendering

I am trying to make a exploded view.

I used this tutorial to export and import from autodesk Inventor. Successfully.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QuxakW1UpsA&t=63s&ab_channel=IlikeBlender

I have tried to replicate the following tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_9GYrjhjtdo&list=WL&index=30&ab_channel=TheCGEssentials

But i get stuck on the last part where the files should expand away from each other. i can pick individual parts and scale them. But not move any of them.

Only difference i can see is that i lack the multiple nodes. But that could be because most of the origins are all centered in the same spot?
[image]
[image]

Additional (same ish) info:  https://linustechtips.com/topic/1393116-any-autodesk-inventorcad-blender-nerds-around-need-help-importingchancing-objects-and-then-to-make-a-exploded-view/

Comment: yes this is because the origins are at the same spot. place them differently: select all and menu "object/set origin/origin to geometry".

Comment: Thanks! It works! whoo. Will update later when complete

Comment: I needed to import a new model but now it does not want to show reused parts. But only some of the duplicate parts. screws and rivets are fine. It must have something to do with the info about the part being reused. Because if i make a copy with different name and replace the old part that did not show in blender it works. I think i can manage but it would be nice to know why this happens.

Comment: It only happens to one of my models. Strange.

Comment: How do i convert a multibody object back to a single object? i have a battery that gets split open but its just a component going in.